# ReferenceError: result is not defined (Angularjs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm new to angular, and i'm stuck with this issue, not sure why is this happening 
any thoughts would be helpful.

This is my service defined :

```
    window.app.factory 'fetchService', ['$http', '$q', '$location', ($http, $q, $location) ->
      {
      estimate: (newEstimate) ->
        def = $q.defer()

        $http.post('/v2/delivery_estimates', newEstimate).
        then (result) ->
        def.resolve result.data
        , (result) ->
        def.reject result.data
        def.promise
}]
```

Here window.app is mapped to `angular.module('appName',[...])`

This is my controller :

```
    window.app.controller 'deliveryCtrl', [  'fetchService', (fetchService) ->

    $scope.setDefaults = ->
    {.... few code ....}
    fetchService.estimate(initialEstimate)
                         .then (result) ->
                           $scope.dWindows = result.delivery_windows
                           $scope.uWindows = result.unavailable_windows
]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coffeescript seems odd. This:

```
then (result) ->
def.resolve result.data
```

should be:

```
then (result) ->
    def.resolve result.data
```

Same thing for the second function